# Spring boot JPA @Query with like and in

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make a method in Repository that will be able to give me list of users, but it didn't return a value.

This is my method:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "select * from mmall_product m where m.status =1 and m.name like CONCAT('%',?1,'%') and m.category_id in (?2)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Product> findByNameAndCategoryIds(String productName, String categoryIdLists);
}
```

This is my `categoryIdLists`:

```
String categoryIdLists = StringUtils.join(categoryIdList, ",");
```

In my navicatfor mysql, I can get the data.

This is my SQL select:

```
select * from mmall_product m where m.status =1 and m.name like CONCAT('%','a','%') and m.category_id in ("100001","100002","100003")
```

This is my return:

```
26  100002  Apple iPhone 7 Plus (A1661) 128G    iPhone 7，.jpeg  detailtext  1422    7   1   2019-03-14 19:45:38 2019-03-14 19:45:58

40  100003  afa   aa    test.jpg    test.jpg,11.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg detailtext  757 100 1   2019-03-14 19:45:38 2019-03-14 19:45:58

42  100003  apple   testtest.jpg    test.jpg,11.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg detailtext  463 100 1   2019-03-14 19:45:38 2019-03-14 19:45:58
```

But in my spring boot, I can't get the return value.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement why you are not going with booleanbuilder instead of @query. For understanding purpose you can go through http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.0/reference/html/ch03.html